# dispatch_async when initializing UIView objects

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

so here is the problem:

I've got a few heavy views with many subviews, which I need to load and then to display. I want to do it asynchronously so that I don't block my main thread. When I tried to do it asynchronously I encountered the following dilemma:

After all of the heavy lifting job has been done and I return to the main queue to actually display that stuff, I get problems. First of all even though everything is done it takes 30-60 seconds for all the views to become visible. Sometimes they get misplaced. What could I be doing wrong and what should I be looking for ?

```
private func loadScrollViews() {
    let qos = Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE.value)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(qos, 0)) { () -> Void in
        // Creating many UIViews
        for var i = 0; i < 100; i++ {
            let view = UIView(frame: someFrame)
            self.viewCollection.append(view)
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.displayViews()
        })
    }
}

private func displayViews() {
    for view in self.viewCollection {
        self.contentView.addSubview(view)
    }
    self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    self.contentView.hidden = false
}
```

After displayViews gets executed as I said views take almost a minute to appear on the screen.

Comment: Update your question with relevant code. We can't help you fix what we can't see.

Comment: Create views on main thread

Comment: Ok, I will not argue that it is not right, but why is so? Any technical insight?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIView` manipulation should be done on main thread
from [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html)

> Threading Considerations
>
> Manipulations to your application’s user interface must occur on the
>   main thread. Thus, you should always call the methods of the UIView
>   class from code running in the main thread of your application. The
>   only time this may not be strictly necessary is when creating the view
>   object itself but all other manipulations should occur on the main
>   thread.

if you have to create many UIView object then do it like this 
`dispatch_async()` but use `main_queue` for this purpose. And one more thing if you want use background thread then think about using `CALayer` we can do most of `CALayer` work on background thread

Comment: More than recommended. UIKit objects are not thread-safe. Creating UIView objects on a background thread is not supported. Don't do that.

Comment: Agreed I should change recommended word